# App crashes on Nsdata persistent storage call

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a method that calls `NSfetch request` when the app resumes from background to active. Sometimes due to the `NsnotificationManager`, there are 2 instances of this method being getting called.

When i look at my app crash log it shows this

```
2   CoreData                        0x30321a90 -[_PFLock lock] + 20
3   CoreData                        0x30332b34 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 776
4   CoreData                        0x30331776 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 610
5   My app                      0x000ee7e0 -[ViewController CheckExistingData] (ViewController.m:350)
```

The statment on line 350 is:

```
 NSArray *array = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
```

This happens sporadically and rarely without any fixed steps to reproduce.When i checked the logs, this usually happened when this method was called 2 times at the same time; one by `NSnotification` Manager and one by View did appear. I tried adding `@syncronided()` to the method that is called two times but i faced the same error. Is there any other way to make sure that the `NSfetch` is accessed by one thread/ like adding a lock or something.

ANy help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to post some of your code using the [@synchronized](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/184745-synchronized-someobject-class.html) before anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

You’re probably violating Core Data concurrency rules.

If your context is of the old thread confinement type, you need to make sure you always accessing it from one thread or serial queue.

If your context is of main queue concurrency type, you need to make sure that you use it either from the main queue or by calling one of `-performBlock...:` methods.

If your context is of private queue concurrency type, you have to use it from one of `-performBlock...:` methods.

Here are some examples.

#### Thread confinement

If you create a context like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
```

Or:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
```

You can use this context (and all the managed objects you get from it) only from one thread or serial queue (where it was created).

#### Private queue concurrency

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

You can work with this context and its managed objects only from the special methods `-performBlock:` and `-performBlockAndWait:`:

```
[context performBlock:^{
    // Assume error and request exist.
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}];
```

#### Main queue concurrency type

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

Same as private queue concurrency type. But because main queue is used, on the main queue you can use the context directly without wrapping calls into `-performBlock...:` methods.

Comment: Updated with examples.